# Flatlist on scroll the app cloese suddenly

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I'm fetching data from an external API and for the Home, I used Flatlist and everything work well, but for my detail screen I used a horizontal Flatlist inside a ScrollView but when I tried to scroll in the Flatlist the app closed without any error or log.

this is the list component:

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    console.log(item);
    return <ProfileCard {...item} />;
};
return (
 <FlatList
   renderItem={renderItem}
   data={props.cast}
   keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
   horizontal
   showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
   removeClippedSubviews
/>
);
```

and the details screen look like that:

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
   <View style={styles.divider} />
   <Text>Cast</Text>
   <ProfileList cast={cast} />
</ScrollView>
```

React Native Environment Info:
System:
OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Memory: 759.29 MB / 7.68 GB
Shell: 4.4.19
Binaries:
Node: 10.15.3
Yarn: 1.12.3
npm: 6.9.0
npmPackages:
react: 16.5.0 => 16.5.0
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz => 0.57.1
npmGlobalPackages:
create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7

Comment: can you show me the log of error ?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, there's no error showing the app just closed without any error

Comment: oh the app force close cause flatlist ? ,try wrap the view <View><Flatlist/></View>

Comment: I tried to wrap it inside a View but the same issue

Comment: @FathurifkiElvariantoGamal Something weird happened when I deleted the images from the FlatList its work as expected I think is a memory issue